# SharIng scope by declaring ng-controller='sameController'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

```
.div1(ng-controller='sameController')
 // some content
.div2(ng-controller='sameController')
 //other content
```

Do the two divs share the same '$scope'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they don't. Two controller instances are created and both create a new scope for themselves.

Share scope depends upon how HTML is organized in your case it seems that div1 and div2 do not follow parent child hierarchy so, scope are neither the same nor inherited from each other.